# How to use v-for in SweetAlert2

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert2, v-for

```js
this.$swal
.fire({
  title: '학교를 검색해주세요.',
  input: 'text',
  inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: 'off'
  },
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: '검색하기',
  cancelButtonText: '취소',
  icon: 'question',
  preConfirm: (school) => {
    return axios.get(`(serverIp)/school?query=${school}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.data.schools)
        this.$swal.fire({
          title:'학교를선택해주세요.',
          html: `<div v-for="(item, index) in response.data.data.schools" :key="index">
                     {{ item.school_name }}
                 </div>`
            })
          })
      },
      allowOutsideClick: () => !this.$swal.isLoading()
 })
```

I've tried this code, but this is what it looks like in html.

```
{{ item.school_name }}
```

How can i do?

I've not use "Sweetalert 2, I hope you'll understand if i can't.

Comment: It looks like you are directly manipulating DOM, it is not rendered in Vue. You should update the `schools` variable after ajax request is successful and update the associated variable in a Vue component

Comment: By looking at https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html sample it seems that you can not use v-for here. May be the `vm.$data` and other `vm` api can be used here. So you need `html: myfunction` which there you manually loop and return the final html string

Comment: you have to do this in vue render if you want to use v-for -> check mounted and updated hooks or create a custom directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vue-sweetalert2` doesn't support rendering HTML templates dynamically, so you can't pass Vue templates this way; but you don't really need to in this case. Instead, you could  generate the HTML string in JavaScript like this:

```js
axios
  .get(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    this.$swal.fire({
      html: response.data.data.schools
              .map(item => `<div>${item.school_name}</div>`)
              .join('')
    })
  })
```

The above code uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the array in `response.data.data.schools` to map the array values into an array of `div`s. Then it uses [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to combine the resulting array values into one long HTML string.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-star-0l8hw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: @Sh031224 No problem :)

Comment: I have another question. How can I do an onclick event in <div>? I've tried to add 'onSelect'  method, and added `onclick="onSelect();"`
But Error with 'Uncaught ReferenceError: onSelect is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick'

Comment: I recommend asking a new question so that someone familiar with the topic can provide an answer.